# contenteditable table cells

Tags: html, editing, contenteditable, tablecell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Contenteditable table row,column modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394251/contenteditable-table-row-column-modifier)

creating a contentEditable table cell  for FF allows the user to enter some text directly into the cell . while doing so the outline of the cell (I think called the focus rectangle ) is overlaid with horizontal and vertical controls.

what are they, what do they do  and how do you prevent them from displaying?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript, Firefox: how to disable the browser specific cell controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737026/javascript-firefox-how-to-disable-the-browser-specific-cell-controls) and [contentEditable table row,column modifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394251/contenteditable-table-row-column-modifier)