# Contenteditable table row,column modifier

Tags: html, contenteditable, w3c

Is there anyway to not display the row and column modification (the 2 arrows and cross) when making a table editable. I went through the W3C draft for contenteditable and it doesn't talk anything about the specific cases of different elements.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand you correctly, the following will do it in Firefox (note: apparently the document must be loaded before this command can be executed. See comments below):

```
 document.execCommand("enableInlineTableEditing", null, false);
```

See also this question: [Javascript, Firefox: how to disable the browser specific cell controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737026/javascript-firefox-how-to-disable-the-browser-specific-cell-controls/4737284#4737284)

Comment: In newer versions of Firefox this throws `Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.execCommand]`

Comment: Looks like you have to wait until the document is fully loaded before calling document.execCommand.

Comment: @MattZukowski: Quite possibly, but did that really warrant a downvote? The approach is correct.

Comment: I didn't find out what the issue was until much later. Not able to un-downvote at this point. I generally downvote answers that I don't find helpful in order to solicit better solutions.

Comment: @MattZukowski: I've edited my answer to include a note about the document needing to be loaded.

Comment: @MattZukowski Document have to be fully loaded AND since FF15 also need to have some contenteditable enabled element.