# ContentEditable in Firefox 3 - table helper arrows appearing in wrong position

Tags: jquery, firefox, contenteditable

When inserting a new row via jQuerys' `after()` function, the standard table helper arrows are vastly off position on the page. (they are off position relative to the td that is being edited). The rows being inserted are using the contenteditable tag.

Reproduced on Firefox 3.

Anybody come up across something similar before? Or alternatively is there any way to disable these arrows?

```
newRow = '<tr class="focus"> <td class="column1"><div contenteditable="true">Date</div></td><td class="column2"><div contenteditable="true">Entity</div></td> <td class="column3"><div contenteditable="true">Instances</div></td><td class="column4 "><div contenteditable="true">Type</div></td><td class="column5"><div contenteditable="true">Rule by</div></td><td class="column6" contenteditable="false"><a class="save">Save</a></td></tr>';
$('.manageRules .edit').live('click', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('tr').prev().after(newRow)
    }
})
```

Comment: worst question ever :( be more articulate and help us with some code.

Comment: @Val: You haven't seen many questions on here then. I understand this one.

Comment: @TimDown thanks. Sorry val if the question wasn't clear enough. I have now added some code, not sure if it will be of any help though more general issue than the specific code I have used. ie. a workaround needed or similar

Comment: @Rhyso  I would recommend you to use firebug, then see userAgent applied css, (most likely is the appearance property on css), or have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394251/contenteditable-table-row-column-modifier its not jquery but if you need help let me know.

Comment: ANSWER FOUND - document.execCommand("enableInlineTableEditing", null, false); via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014666/force-ie8-into-ie7-compatiblity-mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force IE8 Into IE7 Compatiblity Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014666/force-ie8-into-ie7-compatiblity-mode)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to this bugg report in firefox.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=520556

ContentEditable within a positioned element it wrongly placed.