# disable drag/drop icons for focussed contenteditable in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop, contenteditable

Firefox (20.0.1) displays drag & drop icons around contenteditable elements when they are focussed.

How can I disable these icons?

Example below: Arrows around "THREE".

[image: focussed contenteditable element in Firefox showing (expando?) icons around "THREE"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with inline table editing. Here's how to turn it off:

```
// disable table editing
doc.execCommand("enableInlineTableEditing", null, false);
```

from: [Contenteditable table row,column modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394251/contenteditable-table-row-column-modifier)