# Firefox Content Editable remove "help elements"

Tags: html, firefox, contenteditable

I have a huge issue with Firefox, as soon as I create a content editable table, it keeps importing a bunch of "help elements" that I do not want.

Reproduce: 
Open fiddle with firefox (personally, Im using 48.0).

See fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fronjv5o/

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    hello world
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

My question is, how do I remove those "help elements" from ever showing their ugly face again?

In case it wasnt clear enough here is what I am refering too:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And after pouring an hour into this only to find the solution here:
[Contenteditable table row,column modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394251/contenteditable-table-row-column-modifier)

But basically:

```
 document.execCommand("enableInlineTableEditing", null, false);
```

once the DOM has been loaded.